# How to compare tokenized attribute with another attribute

Tags: xml, xslt

So I need to create a new XML file with from XML below. I have a problem with tokenize `values.ll` and compare values with `<TitlePack id.l="15241" />, <TitlePack id.l="....." />`

```
<Pack>
<titlesPacks t="lt">
    <TitlePack id.l="12120" guid.s="570ff1a9-6522-4c0d-8f6e-f0580b8cbc2a">
        <assets t="t">
            <TitleAssets>
                <assets t="lt">
                    <LongAssetInfoMulti attrTagName.s="WEB_Slika_internet" attrName.s="WEB_Slika_internet" values.ll="15241 14553 15239"/>
                </assets>
            </TitleAssets>
        </assets>
    </TitlePack>
    <TitlePack id.l="15241" guid.s="2f178e74-c2f7-4551-8ce2-35661dc119e3">
        <title t="t">
            <Title modifiedBy.s="1" mainStatus.s="New" soundFileName.s="\\Pilotshare\Storage\Images\00004313.jpg" endDate.td="2014-11-22T12:57:39.120" composer.s="" lastModifTime.td="2013-11-22T12:57:39.163" isAversion.l="0" year.td="2013-11-22T12:57:39.120" frameRate.l="0" industry.l="0" itemCode.s="LP_2959" topic.s="" useManualDuration.l="0" albumName.s="" keywordsComment.s=" " createdBy.s="1" frames.l="0" oeuvre.s="" language.s="Slovenian" versionNumber.l="-1" startDate.td="2013-11-22T12:57:39.120" is_rotational_cart.l="0" fadeOut.tp="P0:0:0.000S" isRecorded.l="0" folderId.s="417" isOnline.l="1" labelReference.s="" recordDate.td="2013-11-22T12:57:39.120" createdAt.td="2013-11-22T12:57:39.163" soundFileId.s="17171" languageId.l="187" intro.tp="P0:0:0.000S" medium.l="0" product.l="0" folderName.s="IMAGES" titlePeriod.s="" cut.s="" custom1.s="" replacement.s="" custom2.s="" client.s="" mediaProcessStatus.l="9" interfaceId.l="0" modifiedByName.s="ADMIN" compagnyDispName.s="" type.l="9" soundUnitId.s="3" endOffset.tp="P0:0:0.000S" readRate.l="0" fadeIn.tp="P0:0:0.000S" status.l="0" reader.l="0" titleVersion.s="1" crossfade.tp="P0:0:0.000S" soundUnitName.s="Images" lastWords.s="" voice.s="" modifiedAt.td="2013-11-22T12:57:39.163" yearComposed.td="1899-12-31T23:00:00.000" frameScale.l="0" orchestra.s="" interpretComment.s=" " creator.s="" Id.s="15241" author.s="" no_overwrite.l="0" createdByName.s="ADMIN" name.s="have-love-1" killDate.td="2015-11-22T12:57:39.120" conductor.s="" duration.tp="P533:11:43.676S" beginOffset.tp="P0:0:0.000S" source.s="" manualDuration.tp="P0:0:0.000S" volumeNumber.s="" act.s="">
            </Title>
        </title>
    </TitlePack>
    <TitlePack id.l="14451" guid.s="25886d69-736e-4143-a6d4-1d5affde79d2">
        <title t="t">
            <Title modifiedBy.s="1" mainStatus.s="New" soundFileName.s="\\Pilotshare\Storage\Images\00004005.jpg" endDate.td="2013-12-17T10:19:55.077" composer.s="" lastModifTime.td="2013-06-07T08:35:56.223" isAversion.l="0" year.td="2012-12-17T10:19:55.077" frameRate.l="0" industry.l="0" itemCode.s="LP_2725" topic.s="" useManualDuration.l="0" albumName.s="" keywordsComment.s=" " createdBy.s="1" frames.l="0" oeuvre.s="" language.s="Slovenian" versionNumber.l="-1" startDate.td="2012-12-17T10:19:55.077" is_rotational_cart.l="0" fadeOut.tp="P0:0:0.000S" isRecorded.l="0" folderId.s="417" isOnline.l="1" labelReference.s="" recordDate.td="2012-12-17T10:19:55.077" createdAt.td="2012-12-17T10:19:54.670" soundFileId.s="16389" languageId.l="187" intro.tp="P0:0:0.000S" medium.l="0" product.l="0" folderName.s="IMAGES" titlePeriod.s="" cut.s="" custom1.s="" replacement.s="" custom2.s="" client.s=" ADMIN" mediaProcessStatus.l="9" interfaceId.l="0" modifiedByName.s="ADMIN" compagnyDispName.s="" type.l="9" soundUnitId.s="3" endOffset.tp="P0:0:0.000S" readRate.l="0" fadeIn.tp="P0:0:0.000S" status.l="0" reader.l="0" titleVersion.s="1" crossfade.tp="P0:0:0.000S" soundUnitName.s="Images" lastWords.s="" voice.s="" modifiedAt.td="2013-06-07T08:35:56.223" yearComposed.td="1899-12-31T23:00:00.000" frameScale.l="0" orchestra.s="" interpretComment.s=" " creator.s="" Id.s="14451" author.s="Bobo" no_overwrite.l="0" createdByName.s="ADMIN" name.s="Lighthouse" killDate.td="2014-12-17T10:19:55.077" conductor.s="" duration.tp="P0:0:0.000S" beginOffset.tp="P0:0:0.000S" source.s="" manualDuration.tp="P0:0:0.000S" volumeNumber.s="" act.s="">
            </Title>
        </title>
    </TitlePack>
    <TitlePack id.l="15239" guid.s="3dc41a6e-7011-4bd4-be01-8de04d883808">
        <title t="t">
            <Title modifiedBy.s="1" mainStatus.s="New" soundFileName.s="\\Pilotshare\Storage\Images\00004311.tif" endDate.td="2014-11-22T12:29:47.270" composer.s="" lastModifTime.td="2013-11-22T12:29:47.397" isAversion.l="0" year.td="2013-11-22T12:29:47.270" frameRate.l="0" industry.l="0" itemCode.s="LP_2957" topic.s="" useManualDuration.l="0" albumName.s="" keywordsComment.s=" " createdBy.s="1" frames.l="0" oeuvre.s="" language.s="Slovenian" versionNumber.l="-1" startDate.td="2013-11-22T12:29:47.270" is_rotational_cart.l="0" fadeOut.tp="P0:0:0.000S" isRecorded.l="0" folderId.s="417" isOnline.l="1" labelReference.s="" recordDate.td="2013-11-22T12:29:47.270" createdAt.td="2013-11-22T12:29:47.287" soundFileId.s="17169" languageId.l="187" intro.tp="P0:0:0.000S" medium.l="0" product.l="0" folderName.s="IMAGES" titlePeriod.s="" cut.s="" custom1.s="" replacement.s="" custom2.s="" client.s=" ADMIN" mediaProcessStatus.l="9" interfaceId.l="0" modifiedByName.s="ADMIN" compagnyDispName.s="" type.l="9" soundUnitId.s="3" endOffset.tp="P0:0:0.000S" readRate.l="0" fadeIn.tp="P0:0:0.000S" status.l="0" reader.l="0" titleVersion.s="1" crossfade.tp="P0:0:0.000S" soundUnitName.s="Images" lastWords.s="" voice.s="" modifiedAt.td="2013-11-22T12:29:47.397" yearComposed.td="1899-12-31T23:00:00.000" frameScale.l="0" orchestra.s="" interpretComment.s=" " creator.s="" Id.s="15239" author.s=" ADMIN" no_overwrite.l="0" createdByName.s="ADMIN" name.s="pek2_02" killDate.td="2015-11-22T12:29:47.270" conductor.s="" duration.tp="P0:0:0.000S" beginOffset.tp="P0:0:0.000S" source.s="" manualDuration.tp="P0:0:0.000S" volumeNumber.s="" act.s="">
            </Title>
        </title>
    </TitlePack>
</titlesPacks>
```

I need result like this:

```
<content>
<item>
    <WEB_Slika_internet>
        <Title>
            <soundFileName.s>\\Pilotshare\Storage\Images\00004313.jpg</soundFileName.s>
        </Title>
    </WEB_Slika_internet>
    <WEB_Slika_internet>
        <Title>
            <soundFileName.s>\\Pilotshare\Storage\Images\00004005.jpg</soundFileName.s>
        </Title>
    </WEB_Slika_internet>
    <WEB_Slika_internet>
        <Title>
            <soundFileName.s>\\Pilotshare\Storage\Images\00004311.tif</soundFileName.s>
        </Title>
    </WEB_Slika_internet>
</item>
```

So I compare in XSLT attribute `values.ll` from `LongAssetInfoMulti` tag

```
<Pack>
<titlesPacks t="lt">
    <TitlePack id.l="12120" guid.s="570ff1a9-6522-4c0d-8f6e-f0580b8cbc2a">
        <assets t="t">
            <TitleAssets>
                <assets t="lt">
                    <LongAssetInfoMulti attrTagName.s="WEB_Slika_internet" attrName.s="WEB_Slika_internet" values.ll="15241 14553 15239"/>
                </assets>
            </TitleAssets>
        </assets>
    </TitlePack>
</titlesPacks>
```

to attribute `id.l` from tag `TitlePack`

```
<Pack>
<titlesPacks t="lt">
    <TitlePack id.l="12120" guid.s="570ff1a9-6522-4c0d-8f6e-f0580b8cbc2a" />
    <TitlePack id.l="15241" guid.s="2f178e74-c2f7-4551-8ce2-35661dc119e3" />
    <TitlePack id.l="14451" guid.s="25886d69-736e-4143-a6d4-1d5affde79d2" />
    <TitlePack id.l="15239" guid.s="3dc41a6e-7011-4bd4-be01-8de04d883808" />
</titlesPacks>
```

And if they are the same write attribute `soundFileName.s` (or every attribute) from tag `Title`.

If you have any idea **how to compare tokenized attribute to other attribute** and write it in new XML with XSLT please help.

That's my xsl:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="Pack/titlesPacks/TitlePack">
    <xsl:variable name="list" select="/assets/TitleAssets/assets/LongAssetInfoMulti/@values.ll" />
    <xsl:variable name="item" select="/@id.l" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains(concat(' ', $list, ' '), concat(' ', $item, ' '))">
        <xsl:element name="WEB_Slika_internet">
            <xsl:value-of select="/title/Title/@soundFileName.s"></xsl:value-of>
        </xsl:element>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>

</xsl:template>
```

But I get this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><WEB_Slika_internet></WEB_Slika_internet><WEB_Slika_internet></WEB_Slika_internet>
```

Any new idea?

Comment: Which version of XSLT? And if XSLT 1.0, which processor?

Comment: It's like this in xsl `<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">`

Comment: Your original question already had a suitable answer.  While you can always edit a question to add more information or clarifications to help people provide answers to the original question you asked, if you want to ask a separate follow-on question you should make it a separate Stack Overflow question rather than an edit (and _accept_ the correct answer to this question too).

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessary to tokenize the attribute. You can test if a given item appears in a space-separated list by:

```
<xsl:if test="contains(concat(' ', $list, ' '), concat(' ', $item, ' '))">
```

Of course, comparison with tokenized values is more straightforward - provided your processor supports XSLT 2.0 or the EXSLT str:tokenize() extension function.